# Unable to display the results of OCR

Tags: java, android, ocr

I have this mainActivity java file which I would like to display back the results of the OCR.

1. ERROR: Creation of directory /storage/emulated/0/TesseractSample/tessdata failed, check does Android Manifest have permission to write to external storage.
2. Unable to copy files to tessdata java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/TesseractSample/tessdata/eng.traineddata: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

3.Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/TesseractSample/imgs/ocr.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

4. Data path must contain subfolder tessdata!

   ```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.graphics.Bitmap;
   import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.os.Environment;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.provider.MediaStore;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI;

   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileOutputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.io.OutputStream;

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
       static final int PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
       private TessBaseAPI tessBaseApi;
       TextView textView;
       Uri outputFileUri;
       private static final String lang = "eng";
       String result = "empty";

       private static final String DATA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/TesseractSample/";
       private static final String TESSDATA = "tessdata";

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           Button captureImg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_btn);
           if (captureImg != null) {
               captureImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       startCameraActivity();
                   }
               });
           }
           textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textResult);
       }


       /**
        * to get high resolution image from camera
        */
       private void startCameraActivity() {
           try {
               String IMGS_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/TesseractSample/imgs";
               prepareDirectory(IMGS_PATH);

               String img_path = IMGS_PATH + "/ocr.jpg";

               outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(img_path));

               final Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
               takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

               if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                   startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent data) {
           //making photo
           if (requestCode == PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
               prepareTesseract();
               startOCR(outputFileUri);
           } else {
               Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR: Image was not obtained.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       }

       /**
        * Prepare directory on external storage
        *
        * @param path
        * @throws Exception
        */
       private void prepareDirectory(String path) {

           File dir = new File(path);
           if (!dir.exists()) {
               if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                   Log.e(TAG, "ERROR: Creation of directory " + path + " failed, check does Android Manifest have permission to write to external storage.");
               }
           } else {
               Log.i(TAG, "Created directory " + path);
           }
       }


       private void prepareTesseract() {
           try {
               prepareDirectory(DATA_PATH + TESSDATA);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           copyTessDataFiles(TESSDATA);
       }

       /**
        * Copy tessdata files (located on assets/tessdata) to destination directory
        *
        * @param path - name of directory with .traineddata files
        */
       private void copyTessDataFiles(String path) {
           try {
               String fileList[] = getAssets().list(path);

               for (String fileName : fileList) {

                   // open file within the assets folder
                   // if it is not already there copy it to the sdcard
                   String pathToDataFile = DATA_PATH + path + "/" + fileName;
                   if (!(new File(pathToDataFile)).exists()) {

                       InputStream in = getAssets().open(path + "/" + fileName);

                       OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pathToDataFile);

                       // Transfer bytes from in to out
                       byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                       int len;

                       while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                           out.write(buf, 0, len);
                       }
                       in.close();
                       out.close();

                       Log.d(TAG, "Copied " + fileName + "to tessdata");
                   }
               }
           } catch (IOException e) {
               Log.e(TAG, "Unable to copy files to tessdata " + e.toString());
           }
       }


       /**
        * don't run this code in main thread - it stops UI thread. Create AsyncTask instead.
        * https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
        *
        * @param imgUri
        */
       private void startOCR(Uri imgUri) {
           try {
               BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
               options.inSampleSize = 4; // 1 - means max size. 4 - means maxsize/4 size. Don't use value <4, because you need more memory in the heap to store your data.
               Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgUri.getPath(), options);

               result = extractText(bitmap);

               textView.setText(result);

           } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
           }
       }


       private String extractText(Bitmap bitmap) {
           try {
               tessBaseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
           } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
               if (tessBaseApi == null) {
                   Log.e(TAG, "TessBaseAPI is null. TessFactory not returning tess object.");
               }
           }

           tessBaseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang);

   //       //EXTRA SETTINGS
   //        //For example if we only want to detect numbers
   //        tessBaseApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST, "1234567890");
   //
   //        //blackList Example
   //        tessBaseApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_BLACKLIST, "!@#$%^&*()_+=-qwertyuiop[]}{POIU" +
   //                "YTRWQasdASDfghFGHjklJKLl;L:'\"\\|~`xcvXCVbnmBNM,./<>?");

           Log.d(TAG, "Training file loaded");
           tessBaseApi.setImage(bitmap);
           String extractedText = "empty result";
           try {
               extractedText = tessBaseApi.getUTF8Text();
           } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.e(TAG, "Error in recognizing text.");
           }
           tessBaseApi.end();
           return extractedText;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: `heck does Android Manifest have permission to write to external storage.` Does it?

Comment: Yes I have this line : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're targeting Android SDK 23 or higher, you have to [request permissions from the user at run time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) in addition to requesting permission in the Android manifest file.

Alternatively, you can target SDK 22 or lower by changing the `targetSdkVersion` value in your build.gradle.